# Deleting Core Data objects from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmutablearray, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've got an NSMutableArray that currently holds a bunch of Core Data entities like so:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[fetchReq setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Subject"
                                inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

subjectsArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:nil];
```

I then put this array in a dictionary:

```
_childrenDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[_childrenDictionary setObject:subjectsArray forKey:@"SUBJECTS"];
```

This dictionary is then used as the data for a Source List I have implemented.  What I'm having issues with is deleting an object from the subjectsArray.  I've tried this with the following code:

```
_selectedSubject = [subjectsArray objectAtIndex:0];
[subjectsArray removeObject:subjectToDelete];
```

Now this works fine, when I execute the following:

```
for (Subject *s in subjectsArray) {
        NSLog(@"Subjects: %@", [s title]);
    }
```

The Subject I selected to delete is no longer there and the Source List I have updates correctly after calling:

```
[_sidebarOutlineView reloadData];
```

The problem I am having though is that when I quit the application and open it up again, the Subject I previously deleted is still there.

The fetching of the core data entities into the array and dictionary is done inside *applicationDidFinishLaunching*.  At the moment all this code is inside the AppDelegate file, which has a .h file that looks like this:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Subject.h"

@interface LTAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSOutlineViewDelegate,     NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSMenuDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSWindow *newSubjectSheet;
    IBOutlet NSWindow *newNoteSheet;
    IBOutlet NSWindow *newEditSheet;
    NSMutableArray *subjectsArray;
}

@property Subject *selectedSubject;
@property (assign)IBOutlet NSOutlineView *sidebarOutlineView;
@property NSArray *topLevelItems;
@property NSViewController *currentContentViewController;
@property NSMutableDictionary *childrenDictionary;
@property NSArray *allSubjects;
```

Any ideas as to what is causing to deleted Subject to reappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing the objects from the local array, but not the CoreData store itself.

To remove an object from the Core Data store, you need to call `managedObjectContext 
deleteObject:theObject` on it, and then call `managedObjectContent save:&error` to persist it.

If you are using table views, I would recommend checking out the NSFetchedResultsController as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit your changes to the `NSManagedObjectContext` for it to persist.

check out the `save:&errorOut` method on that class for details.

Comment: side note: you can get the `NSManagedObjectContext` off of any CoreData object: `[obj.managedObjectContext save:error]`

Comment: That's handy to know, will come in handy when it comes to refactoring. Thanks